# Create SQL View from X,Y,Z columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains 3 columns: X,Y,Z.

X and Y will contain a list of integers, and Z will contain some text.

For Instance

```
X Y  Z
1 1 'A'
1 2 'B'
2 1 'C'
2 2 'D'
3 1 'E'
3 2 'F'
```

I want to display the values into a Matrix, so that it looks like this

```
A B
C D
E F
```

The values in X and Y can vary, such as X will contain values 1 thru 6, and Y will be 1 thru 5, but there SHOULD be 30 entries (i.e. 5 * 6 = 30), but I would like to handle situations where there is a missing entry.

How can I do this and store it into a view, elegantly?

UPDATE: This needs to be done without knowing the values in X and Y ahead of time, as it could change, but there will only ever be this many columns

Comment: if it's dynamic, meaning it could be 2 columns or it could be 5, then you'd need to always have 5 columns for it to work in a view.  In that case you could use pivot or  max(case) statements

Answer (score 2):

Basically, what you want to do is to [*pivot*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) the table:

```
SELECT x, [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]
  FROM (SELECT x, y, z FROM myTable) AS source
 PIVOT (MIN(z) FOR [y] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])) AS pivoted
```

which should (untested) yield:

```
x 1 2 3 4 5
-----------
1 A B
2 C D
3 E F
```

(with missing values containing NULL).

Note that you need to *fix* the number of columns that your SQL returns, so it's not possible to skip columns 3-5 if they are unused. In other words, if the maximum value of y is unknown, there's no possibility to do this with (static) SQL.

Adding missing rows with a [numbers table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/11506/5273) is left as an exercise.

Comment: this wouldn't solve the issue where X and Y can be any range of values which is determined in the table

Comment: @TruthOf42: SQL Server does not support creating a view with a variable number of columns. Thus, the problem *in its general form* simply *cannot* be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.z, t2.z 
from table t1 
join table t2 
      on t1.x = t2.x 
     and t1.y = 1
     and t2.y = 2
```

Comment: this wouldn't solve the issue where Y can another range of values that is determined in the table

Comment: Then just extend the joins.  Answer is only as good as the question.